# How to keep a page with a figure and caption on a separate page in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a paper that has text pages as well as pages with a figure and caption that need to be kept on a separate page. I would like to be able to "lock" the figure and caption on that separate page so that they do not move even if I add text to the pages before/after the figure page. The formatting I would like is something like:

Page 1: Text that mentions figure
Page 2: Figure with caption
Page 3: Continuing text from page 1

Right now every time I add or remove text throughout the document, all of the figures and captions get moved to no longer be on a separate page and I would like to avoid having to reformat as there is a page limit that I need to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them as a separate object, not in the overall 'flowing' text.
Insert a textbox, anchor it on the page, and then copy the relevant parts and insert them into the textbox. They will stay there, and the rest of the document will flow before and after it.